# Typename and Struct definition in C++98

Tags: c++, c++98

There is a problem with usage of `typenames` with `struct` in the *old C++ standard*. I have the following error:

> error: no matching function for call to

This is what I get when compiling with `C++98 standard`. With `C++11` and newer, it works as I expect.

I defined a struct with a `template` and in the `main()` function I initialized the `Pair` from my `templated struct` with some values. Then I print the members of the struct:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct Pair
{
    T first = 0;
    T second = 0;
};

int main()
{
    Pair<int> p1 { 5, 6 };        
    std::cout << p1.first << ' ' << p1.second << '\n';

    p1 = { 2, 3 }; 
    std::cout << p1.first << ' ' << p1.second << '\n';


    return 0;
}
```

GDB Compiler tells me:
`main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: main.cpp:12:25: error: no matching function for call to ‘Pair::Pair()’ 12 |     Pair<int> p1 { 5, 6 };`

But if we change declaration of members in the struct to this:

```
struct Pair
{
    T first;
    T second;
};
```

It works correctly.

Can somebody explain why it works like this?

Comment: I don't see how it could _"work correctly"_ with `Pair<int> p1{5, 6};`  and `p1 = { 2, 3 };` in C++98 as you claim. [It fails everywhere](https://godbolt.org/z/3MGba14qc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default member initializers were a feature added to the language in C++11.  That means that the `= 0` part of your `Pair` member declarations is ill-formed before C++11.

Uniform initialization syntax was also added in C++11, which means that `Pair<int> p1 { 5, 6 }` and `p1 = { 2, 3 }` are also ill-formed prior to C++11.

Changing the definition of `Pair` as you did fixes the first issue, but not the second.  To get the same functionality with C++98 you will need to add user-defined constructors to `Pair`:

```
template <typename T>
struct Pair
{
    T first;
    T second;

    Pair() : first(), second() {}
    Pair(T f, T s) : first(f), second(s) {}
};

int main()
{
    Pair<int> p1(5, 6);
    std::cout << p1.first << ' ' << p1.second << '\n';

    p1 = Pair<int>(2, 3);
    std::cout << p1.first << ' ' << p1.second << '\n';


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Initializer lists didn't become a standalone production in the grammar until C++11, so `p1 = { 2, 3 };` (which is NOT an initialization, so "uniform initialization" is irrelevant) is ill-formed prior to C++11 even if Pair is an aggregate, while the initialization `Pair<int> p1 = { 2, 3 };` is accepted for an aggregate.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yeah, I don't know why I thought that was valid pre-C++11.  Updated the answer.